# Defining makefile variable at build time and using it in foreach

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, recipe

I am defining a makefile variable by parsing a json file using `jq`.

```
define variable
    $(eval objects := $(shell jq -c '.abc.values[]' config.json))
endef
target_a:
    $(variable)
    @echo "from target-a: $(objects)"
target_b: $(foreach X, $(objects), stage_$(X))
```

I am getting an output that's the same as the json list:

```
from target-a: first second
```

This means the variable is getting initialized correctly but the foreach is not triggering any `stage_%` targets. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your makefile cannot work.  Make proceeds in two distinct steps: *first* all makefiles are entirely parsed and an internal graph of the targets and prerequisites is created.  *Second* make walks that graph and invokes all the recipes.  All prerequisites must be defined during the first step.  All recipes are only expanded during the second step.

Here, you've added the expansion of the `objects` variable into the recipe for `target_a`, so that will not happen until the second step, IF make decides to rebuild the target `target_a` because it's out of date.  But, the definition of the prerequisites of `target_b` has already happened a long time ago, when make was parsing the makefile in the first step.

You can do this in your example and it will work:

```
objects := $(shell jq -c '.abc.values[]' config.json)

target_a:
        @echo "from target-a: $(objects)"

target_b: $(foreach X, $(objects), stage_$(X))
```

Here, `objects` is expanded as the makefile is parsed and so it will have a value before `target_b` is expanded.

Maybe there's some reason you can't do it this way, but if so you've simplified your example too much for us to help.

Comment: Yeah, that worked by using your approach. Thanks for the precise explanation.

Comment: Is there any way to run those foreach pre-requisites parsed in second step? I want the `$(objects)` variable initialized in a recipe during build time.

Comment: Well, that cannot work in the makefile you have here, because target_b is not related in any way to target_a, so there's no insurance that target_b's recipe will be run before target_a is considered... and so `objects` will have no value.  I suspect that this is an XY problem and you've gone far enough afield from your actual requirements that you're trying to solve problems that you don't need to solve.  For example, why do you want the variable set by a recipe?

Comment: You might find some answers in this series of blog posts: http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/  Read them from the bottom-up (in order).  Pay particular attention to article V, Constructed Include Files.

Comment: I read your blog, it's really a great resource for makefiles. So in short I want the variable set by a recipe because the `config.json` file is exported json from `terraform output -json > $(CONFIG)`. I want `objects` to have those values parsed from `$(CONFIG)` file.

Comment: The typical way to do that is to add `include generated_deps.d` to your makefile, then write a rule with the target `generated_deps.d: config.json` with a recipe that converts the input file into an output file which contains the generated dependencies (in your case, something like,  `echo "target_b: $$(jq -c '.abc.values[]' $<)" > $@`)